# jquery addclass method not working with href link with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

issue with  `$("#mylink").attr("href",uri);` if i use this i cannot able to use addclass method to add active class that is if i use only `$("#mylink").addClass('active')` its working fine but if i use along with `$("#mylink").attr("href",uri).addClass('active');`  active class is not taking .here my uri is '`sysadmin_delivery_ready.html?uid="+testnum`' please help me regarding this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mylink").click(function() {
    var getuid = $ {
      userId
    };
    var testnum = btoa(getuid);
    var uri = "sysadmin_delivery_ready.html?uid=" + testnum;
    $("#mylink").attr("href", uri);
    var clsval = this.className;
    if (clsval == '') {
      alert("blank");
      $("#mylink").addClass('active');
    } else {
      alert("ac");
      $("#mylink").removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Data
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> General Information
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="mylink">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Deliver
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `var getuid = $ {userId};` Seems to be erroneous..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3qc9oxvg/10/ Cannot reproduce this issue. Tried with jQuery 3.3.1 in a fiddle (given above).

Answer (score 0):

Please find a working snippet here:

As I didn't really change the functionnality of your code, can you comment to tell me what is wrong with it?
I didn't get it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mylink").click(function() {
    // I commented some of the code to have a working snippet…
    /*var getuid = $ {
      userId
    };
    var testnum = btoa(getuid);
    var uri = "sysadmin_delivery_ready.html?uid=" + testnum;*/
    
    var uri = "#foo"; // Added for test
    $("#mylink").attr("href", uri);
    var clsval = this.className;
    if (clsval == '') {
      // … and changed alert into console.log
      console.log("blank");
      $("#mylink").addClass('active');
    } else {
      console.log("ac");
      $("#mylink").removeClass('active');
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Data
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> General Information
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="mylink">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Deliver
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I added FontAwesome 4 and stylized `li` and the `active` class to get a better output.

Answer (score 0):

> Your chaining is not correct, you should use

```
$("#mylink").addClass('active').attr("href",uri);
```

instead of

```
$("#mylink").attr("href",uri).addClass('active');
```

but I would suggest you to use  below code and change into this according to your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mylink").click(function() {
    var getuid = $ {  userId  };
    var testnum = btoa(getuid);
    var uri = "sysadmin_delivery_ready.html?uid=" + testnum;
    $(this).toggleClass('active').attr("href",uri);   
  });
});
```